# Delphi fire frame events from datamodule

Tags: delphi, events, frame

I've an application made by a main form, a frame and a datamodule.
When the main form is created I create also the frame wich contains the fields present in a table that are in the datamodule.
So the main form code is this:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  FraDtl;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FFraDtl: TfraDetail;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFraDtl := TfraDetail.Create(Self);
  FFraDtl.Parent := Self;
end;

end.
```

The code of the frame is this:

```
unit FraDtl;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  database, cxGraphics, cxControls, cxLookAndFeels, cxLookAndFeelPainters,
  cxContainer, cxEdit, cxTextEdit, cxDBEdit, Vcl.StdCtrls, dxSkinsCore,
  cxNavigator, cxDBNavigator;

type
  TfraDetail = class(TFrame)
    lblCognome: TLabel;
    edtCognome: TcxDBTextEdit;
    lblNome: TLabel;
    edtNome: TcxDBTextEdit;
    cxDBNavigator1: TcxDBNavigator;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

And the code of the datamodule is this:

```
unit database;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Data.DB, DBAccess, MSAccess, MemDS,
  dxSkinsCore, cxClasses, cxLookAndFeels, dxSkinsForm;

type
  TdmData = class(TDataModule)
    Connection: TMSConnection;
    tblAutori: TMSTable;
    dsAutori: TMSDataSource;
    fAut_IdAutore: TIntegerField;
    fAut_Cognome: TStringField;
    fAut_Nome: TStringField;
    fAut_Nominativo: TStringField;
    SkinController: TdxSkinController;
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure dsAutoriStateChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  dmData: TdmData;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TdmData.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tblAutori.Open;
end;

procedure TdmData.DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tblAutori.Close;
end;

procedure TdmData.dsAutoriStateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Some stuff
end;

end.
```

I would like to call a procedure present in the frame in the dsAutoriStateChange event is fired. There is a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to access the datamodule inside the frame, or stuff from the main unit?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to call a procedure present in the frame in the dsAutoriStateChange event is fired.

You can do this using code like this:

```
unit database;
....
implementation

uses FraDtl;

procedure TdmData.dsAutoriStateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FraDtl.SomeProcedure; 
end;
```

Or if you want to access the actual instantiated frame you access the main unit.

```
unit database;
....
implementation

uses main;  //circular reference allowed in implementation

procedure TdmData.dsAutoriStateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmMain.FrameDetail.DoSomething(Sender); 
end;
```

In that case you need to add an public property to `frmMain` exposing the frame.

```
TfrmMain = class(TForm)
...
public
  property FrameDetail: TFraDetail read FFraDtl;
```

**Warning**
These kinds of hard coupling between data module and form are considered bad programming practice.
[Loose coupling is good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)
[Hard coupling is bad](http://hokstad.com/why-coupling-is-always-bad-cohesion-vs-coupling)

It would be better to use an event handler for a datasource inside the mainform, or if that's not possible to add additional properties to `TdmData` that get updated by the main form as needed.
The event handler `dsAutoriStateChange` can then access these properties instead of having to poke around in the private parts of the frame.

Comment: Hi Johan, I've used your Idea of accessing the instantiated frame. I would like to use an event handler, but I don't know how to define it in order to do the task I want.

Comment: Best to ask a new question: how to add an event handler to a frame.